# Express reads blank body from Axios POST, despite using middleware?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm attempting to POST from a React app to an Express API I have made.

Using Postman, I'm able to POST data just fine using 'x-www-form-urlencoded'.

I have attempted to do the same from the React application, but every time the API reads the req.body as blank and undefined. When I console.log() the request body and the headers from the React application side, they show data. But console logging the request body from the API's perspective, it is blank.

Relevant API code:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './secrets.env' });
app.use(cors());

app.use('/longhorns/add', express.urlencoded({extended: true}));


 app.post('/longhorns/add', function (req, res) {

  sqlRequest(res, "EXEC AddLonghorn @Name = '" + req.body.Name + "', @RanchPrefix = '" + req.body.RanchPrefix + "', @RoleID = " + parseInt(req.body.RoleID) + ", @SexID = " + parseInt(req.body.SexID) + ", @FatherLonghornID = " + parseInt(req.body.FatherLonghornID) + ", @MotherLonghornID = " + parseInt(req.body.MotherLonghornID) + ", @ReferenceNumber = '" + req.body.ReferenceNumber + "', @DOB = '" + req.body.DOB + "', @Description = '" + req.body.Description + "'");
 });
```

Relevant React app code:

```
  let submitLonghorn = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const longhorn = {
      name,
      ranchPrefix,
      roleID,
      sexID,
      fatherLonghornID,
      motherLonghornID,
      referenceNumber,
      dob,
      description
    }

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'appliation/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }


    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8081/longhorns/add', longhorn, config)
    .then(() => console.log("Longhorn added"))
    .catch(err => {console.error(err)});

  };
```

I tried manually setting the Axios headers to x-www-form-urlencoded to no avail, and made sure to set the API app to use the middleware included with Express. I also tried the suggestion of another post here to change the app.use(express.X()) statement to express.json() [while also changing the axios request to not be x-www-form-urlencoded], but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure this is all the issues but you need to return your promise from the async method else it will terminate potentially before completion. Try:

```
let submitLonghorn = async (e: any) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   
   const longhorn = {
     name,
     ranchPrefix,
     roleID,
     sexID,
     fatherLonghornID,
     motherLonghornID,
     referenceNumber,
     dob,
     description
   }

   const config = {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'appliation/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }
   }

try {
   return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8081/longhorns/add', longhorn, config)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and used it, but the API is still receiving a blank req.body

Comment: I ended up solving this issue by switching to fetch and implementing useEffect